# UDP Multicast between PC and Android ICS (CSharp vs. Java)

Tags: c#, udp, multicast, udpclient

i've got a little problem that causes me serious headaches.
I wrote two small programs for UDP communication (each of them receives and sends).

Tests so far: 
- PC sends packet and receives it.
- Android sends packet and receives it.
After another test between 2 PCs inside the same Network it seems 
that even those 2 do not talk to each other.

The Java-code used for the android device was mainly adopted 
from a (working) program i wrote for Android clustering (so i asume it is correct).

Does anyone have any ideas on that (or might it even be an firewall related issue)?
Some code (only essential parts, monitoring and management of Lists stripped-down e.g.)

Init:

```
private UdpClient udpClient;
private static int udpPort=9998;
private IPAddress mCastAddress = IPAddress.Parse("239.255.255.255");
```

In Ctor:

```
udpClient = new UdpClient(udpPort);
udpClient.MulticastLoopback = true;
udpClient.EnableBroadcast = true;
udpClient.AllowNatTraversal(true);
udpClient.JoinMulticastGroup(mCastAddress);
```

Sender Thread:

```
IPEndPoint iep = new IPEndPoint(mCastAddress, udpPort);           
//MessageCoder.encode(msg) is returning a valid byte[], no problem here.
byte[] data=MessageCoder.encode(msg);
udpClient.Send(data, data.Length, iep);
```

Receiver Thread:

```
IPEndPoint iep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
byte[] data = udpClient.Receive(ref iep);
```

Thanks in advance.
[EDIT]
I shall mention that it does not seem that the android device does receive 
any packages fron my pc as well.
[/EDIT]

Comment: Shouldn't the receiver's end point listen on the same port as the sender?

Comment: Port `0` usually doesn't work :)

Comment: Well, Port 0 is just there because of desperate googl'ing; It does not work with another port as well :(

Comment: Are you going through a NAT? Multicast does not travel through routers unless they are specifically configured.

Comment: For some clarification: At the beginning i only used members MulticastLoopback anf JoinMulticastGroup. The others were added because it did not work so far. I'll do some tests now. Thanks so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i found a solution for the PC <-> PC problem:

In Ctor:

```
udpClient = new UdpClient(udpPort);
udpClient.MulticastLoopback = true;
udpClient.EnableBroadcast = true;
udpClient.JoinMulticastGroup(mCastAddress);
```

In Sender Thread:

```
 IPEndPoint iep = iep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, udpPort);
```

In Receiver Thread:

```
IPEndPoint iep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any,udpPort);
```

Sometimes it's the small things...

Now it's time to try the interop with my Android device.

Comment: Well, finally everything works. Strange thing is: to get all running together i **have** to send to Broadcast (255.255.255.255). Well if it runs, don't complain :)